# Maximum time for HTML metatag refresh

Tags: html

In

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="n">
```

Is there a maximum value for n? Is there a number large enough to where the browser, or whatever is counting down, will fail to refresh after n seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not. At least not within reasonable terms...I'm sure there's a limit to an HTML attribute, but the amount of numbers you could fit into that limit would cause the refresh to take so long you'd probably fall asleep. :P

Answer (score 11):

[WebKit uses `double` to store the delay.](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/dom/Document.cpp#L1970)

Comment: So the maximum is probably in the range of several years.